# Throw a game object via C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Having a little trouble of getting a game object thrown. I had a 2d game where by the game object i want thrown is a grenade. At the moment, I have the following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]

public class SoldierController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject grenadeObject;

     void Start()
        {
            grenadeObject.SetActive(false); 
        }

    void Update()
    {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
                    {
                        grenadeObject.SetActive(true);
                        animator.SetBool("Grenade", true);
                        GrenadeThrow();
                        //speed = Mathf.Lerp(10, 0, Time.deltaTime);
                       // grenadeObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 10);
                        StartCoroutine(GrenadeCooldown());
                    }

     }

    void GrenadeThrow()
        {
            StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Grenade"));
            Instantiate(grenadeObject, new Vector3(10 * 2.0F, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }


        IEnumerator GrenadeCooldown()
        {
            canFire = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
            //rifleMuzzle.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().top();
            canFire = true;
            animator.SetBool("Grenade",false);
        }
}
```

I would expect the object to at least be thrown out of the character hand except nothing happens at all. Any help/?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a component on the grenadeObject prefab, e.g. Grenade script. In there you would have a Vector3 for the direction it should go and a float for the speed. In that script's `Start()`, you would use the speed and direction to fire the grenade. The speed and direction are assigned by the class you provided in the question.

Here is an example Grenade class:

```
public class Grenade : Monobehaviour {

    public Vector3 direction;
    public float speed;

    void Start () {

        // initiate movement of the grenade

    }

}
```

Your class updated from the question:

```
public GameObject grenadeObject;

void Update() {

   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I)) {

       animator.SetBool("Grenade", true);
       GrenadeThrow();

    }

}

void GrenadeThrow() {

    StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Grenade")); // unknown function
    Grenade grenade = Instantiate(grenadeObject, new Vector3(10 * 2.0F, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Grenade> ();
    grenade.direction = Vector3.one; // change this to the appropriate direction
    grenade.speed = 10f; // change this to the appropriate speed

}


IEnumerator GrenadeCooldown() {

    canFire = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
    //rifleMuzzle.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().top();
    canFire = true;
    animator.SetBool("Grenade",false);
}
```

Comment: Hi There,

Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this has resulted in the following error:

The type or namespace name `Grenade' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: You will need to create a Grenade class and add it to the grenadeObject prefab, or use a class you've already added to the prefab.  I will put an example in the answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So I created a new C# script with a class Grenade, all is well but it has come up with another error.  Type `UnityEngine.Object' does not contain a definition for `GetComponent' and no extension method `GetComponent' of type